# Does Jetty require JDK if you are not using JSP

Tags: jetty, java

Assuming your application is not compiling anything and does not use JSP pages, is it fine to run Jetty using just the JRE, or is there some other requirement to run on the JDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JRE, even for JSP compiling, as the JSP support has the Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) built-in.